# Is there a website to find games by gameplay elements?

Tags: pc

Is there a website where you can find games not just by genre, but also by specific gameplay elements? I'm thinking of something similar to how Pandora music streaming tags songs with specific musical elements in addition to its genre.

For example, if I am looking for racing games, not only do I want to search just the general racing genre, but perhaps I would like to find racing games with "customization" as an element, or exclude racing games with a "story" element.

Is there any website or database like this on the web?

Note to mods: I couldn't find an appropriate tag for this question. If this is a valid question for the site, could you please re-tag? Thanks!

Comment: On Steam you can search by tag, which is probably as close as you're going to get